# How do I make a new plane of my mesh selection?

Tags: modeling, interface, vertices

[image]

Hello Blender Community,
I basically doubled these stairs and want the double to be its own Plane.
Is there a shortcut for creating a new plane with my mesh selection?

Best

Comment: do you mean that you want to separate it as a new object? It's P > Separate Selection

Comment: Press P (separate), and pick "By Selection".

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode, with the faces of the part you want to separate selected, press P and then choose "Separate selection". The selected faces will be separated into a new object.
You can also choose "Separate by loose parts", which automatically separates each loose part of the mesh into its own object.

[image]